# Loading a c program in another one

Tags: c, include, codeblocks

I have written a program and i want to link it to another c program. In the sense, by using the include or any other directive, I need to link the programs, such that a function of the former can be called by the latter. How can i accomplish this in codebloacks ?

Comment: Both cannot have main() function.

Comment: It seems that one of your programs should become a library (redesign is needed). But maybe you are talking about inter-process communication.... Clarify the question

Comment: Basically, suppose i have written a program A with a function c. Now i write a program B. Now, I want  that program A should be included or imported in program B, so that i can call c and use its result in B. It doesn't involve send or receive, just a change in the header files, so it isn't inter-process communication.

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler? Notice that *CodeBlocks* is not a compiler but an IDE....

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04  .. Oh yea, Sorry, GNU GCC compiler .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have now two programs A and B. And in A you have function `c`. So, move `c` to separate file `c.c` and make `c.h` file, that can be included in both A and B program as `#include "c.h"`. Than compile A and B independently.

It will be the simplest way.

**EDIT:**

All function that uses one another should be in the "library". E.g.:

```cpp
// c.h
int c(int x1, int x2); // this will be called from outside

extern int callCount; // to be available outside
```

and

```cpp
// c.c
#include "c.h"

int d(int x); // this cannot be called from outside

// global variable to count calls of c function
int callCount = 0; 

int c(int x1, int x2)
{
    callCount++; // changing of global variable
    return (x1 + x2) * d(x1);
}

int d(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

and usage

```cpp
// prog A
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c.h"

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    printf("c = %d\n", c(a, b));
    printf("c = %d\n", c(2*a, b - 1));
    printf("Function c was called %d times\n", callCount);
    return 0;
}
```

All the functions that you are planning to call from other files should be declared in h-file. It is the common approach, but also lots of tips can be find in the Internet, such as `static` functions, `#define` detectives and conditional compilation, etc.

Comment: Actually, i might need more than 1 function, and all the functions are linked . So is there a way that i can include whole of A in B. Also, how are 'c.h' files made

Comment: @AnkitaPrasad : Think over what function should be called from outside and put their declarations in h-file... see example in the **edit**. Just try and read compiler's and linker's messages

Comment: How is a file created with the .h extension?

Comment: Just copy headers of functions in the editor (and add `;` instead of `{ }`). Do you use any IDE?

Comment: @AnkitaPrasad : refer to general explanation at http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/module.php

Comment: My problem is that this function  - int toParser()
{
    sort(hc);
        ik=hc[i];
        return  ik;
}

Comment: uses the array hc and function sort defined in program A, after i create the .h file, and subsequent .c file, how will hc and sort be linked to the ones in program A?

Comment: I have some other work. I will not be able to reply for a few hours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can include the function sort in my c.c and c.h file, but how will i be able to access hc[] out of program A? hc[] is a global variable being modified by different parts of the program

Comment: @AnkitaPrasad : I have added global `int callCount` variable as an example of `extern` declaration in header file. In your case, `hc[]` should be defined in the `c.c` and declared as `extern` in c.h

Comment: VolAnd, Thanks for your help and Sorry for the delay.  My problem is that hc[] is an array whose result is being computed by other parts of the program and then it is being sent to this program. So hc[] cannot be defined, but only used here,

Comment: @AnkitaPrasad : In the example variable `callCount` defined in `c.c` is global for all c-files where `c.h` included, because of `extern int callCount;`. You can make such declaration for your array, so functions from any module will have access to that data (it will be shared memory).

Comment: Thannnkkkssss :). I'll try this and let you know asap.

Answer (score 1):

It (loading a C program in another one) cannot be stricto sensu done, since there is only one single `main` function in any given program. However the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) & [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) functions enable you to start another program -thru a command line- from a first one. On Linux and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems you also can start a process using [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and you can execute a program in a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) using [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Of course this is operating system specific!

However, on some operating systems and platforms, you can use [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) to load some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) at *runtime*. The loaded plugin is *not* a program (it does not have any `main` function), but a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29).

For example, on Linux and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems, you could use the [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) function to load a plugin (often some [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries)), and the [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) function to get a symbol inside it.

On Linux, `dlopen` is loading an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object which should contain [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

PS. You can also link a library (at build time) to your program.